# Linux how to sort parameters

Tags: linux, shell

When I want to run my parameter with `-sort` after it, I need to sort all the other parameters that I mention with it. Example

```
. MyScript.sh -sort Tree Apple Boolean
```

The output should need to be

```
Apple 
Boolean
Tree
```

I tried to make an array and run through all the parameters but this didn't work out

```
Array=()
while (( "$#" ))
do
  Array += "$1"
  shift
done
```

This also had the problem that I couldn't ignore the `-sort`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "-sort" ]; then
    shift;
    echo "$@" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | tr '\n' ' ';
    echo;
else
    echo "$@";
fi
```

Explanation: the first `if` checks if the first argument is `-sort`. If it is, it shifts the arguments, so `-sort` goes away but the other arguments remain. Then the arguments are run through `tr` which turns the space separated list into a newline separated one (which `sort` requires), then it pipes that through `sort` which finally prints the sorted list (converted back to space-separated format). If the first argument is not `-sort`, then it just prints the list as-is.

Comment: Somehow I would have guessed that if the `-sort` option were not present, the `Tree Apple Boolean` should have been output in just that order. If that is what really needed, put the shown `echo` into the `if` block, and make an `else` where output is done without the sort

Comment: @Carbonic-acid now that's a true beauty

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this and add to it as per your requirements. :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "-sort" ]; then
    shift;
    my_array=("$@")
    IFS=$'\n' my_sorted_array=($(sort <<<"${my_array[*]}"))
    printf "%s\n" "${my_sorted_array[@]}"
else
    echo "$@"
fi
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~] ./s.sh -sort apple doggie ball cat
apple
ball
cat
doggie
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ "X$1" = "X-sort" ]
then shift; printf "%s\n" "$@" | sort
else        printf "%s\n" "$@"
fi
```

The `then` clause prints the parameters, one per line (trouble if a parameter contains a newline), and feeds that to `sort`.  The `else` clause lists the parameters in their original (unsorted) order.  The use of [`X` with `test`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852612/bash-test-for-empty-string-with-x/6853353#6853353) probably isn't 100% necessary, but avoids any possibility of misinterpretation of the arguments to `test` (aka `[`).

---

One problem with your code fragment is the spaces around the `+=` in:

```
Array += "$1"
```

Shell does not like spaces around the assignment operator; you needed to write:

```
Array+="$1"
```