# Reason of adding "_" in the if comparison "if [ "_$str" = "_" ]; then ....; fi"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I see many times in the shell scripts that they use `"_"` in the if comparison as indicated below:

```
if [ "_$str" = "_" ]; then ....; fi
```

the above code check if the str variable is empty with the comparison `if [ "_$str" = "_" ]`.

Why do not use `if [ "$str" = "" ]`? why adding `"_"` in both strings?

Comment: It seems a good way to skip empty strings comparison. Appending a character in both strings avoids edge cases and keeps the results.

Comment: Simply use `[ -z "${str}" ]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash test for empty string with X""](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852612/bash-test-for-empty-string-with-x)

Comment: @devnull Interestingly, that command would succeed indirectly in affected shells. If `$str` were empty, the expansion would be incorrectly removed, leaving `[ -z ]`. That, however, might be treated as a non-empty string (not the operator `-z`), which would evaluate as true anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do shell script comparisons often use x$VAR = xyes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174119/why-do-shell-script-comparisons-often-use-xvar-xyes)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know it is for historical reasons.  There once were (and maybe on some obscure systems still are) shells which had (have) trouble handling empty strings (and maybe strings starting with dashes).  Hence the simple idea to prevent empty strings (and option-like looking ones) altogether by adding a prefix.  All common shells today do not have these problems anymore.

Comment: That's what I heard as a reason when I saw this first around 1992.  So probably today it is for ancient or prehistoric reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess that before learning how to use quotes properly, the writers of the scripts you've seen had trouble with something like

```
if [[ $str = "" ]]; then ....
```

which will fail if $str is empty, as the argument expands to nothing.  Whereas

```
if [[ _$str = _ ]]
```

will work, but is a kludge.

Comment: The problem predates the `[[...]]` expression in `bash` (which handles expansions of null-valued parameters fine), and was in fact a real bug in the handling of quoted, null-valued parameters by the `test` command in the old Bourne shell.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `[` is an alias to the command `test`. The question is what would happen if your string started with a dash?

In old versions of `test` when using the standard Bourne shell, you'd get an error:

```
$ test -gt = "some_string"
invalid argument
```

The same thing would happen with an `if`

```
$ string="-gt"
$ if [ "$string" = "some_other_string" ]
> then
> echo "Match"
> else
> echo "No Match"
> fi
if: invalid argument
```

That's because the `test` command would see the parameter with a dash and assume that it's a command argument, then either it's an invalid command argument, or the format of the command is incorrect. If you use `[[` instead of `[`, it's not an issue at all because `[[` is a built in test for the `if`.

This is no longer an issue. The `[` and `test` are internal commands to both the Kornshell and BASH, and these shells can handle this issue. Even the newer versions of test are no longer thrown:

```
$ test -gt = "some_string"  # No error.
$ echo $?
1
```

However, older scripts, and those people who either learned from an older timer, or were back writing scripts when system with 32 Mb of memory running on a 16 Mhz 386 chip with Xenix was a state of the art system have gotten into the habit. I use to use `x`:

```
if [ x$var = x$foo ]
```

Comment: +1 for hinting on problems with arguments starting with a dash (so not only empty strings might pose a problem).

Comment: @Alfe If you surround the string with quotes, it's not an issue. That is `[ "$foo" = "$bar" ]` is fine even if one or the other variable is empty. However, it is a problem without quotes. `[ $foo = $bar ]` can cause problems.

Comment: Forgetting the quotes always was and still is a problem.  That prefix thing which is the topic here is independent from correct quoting.