# Why testing for non-empty string using -n always true?

Tags: string, bash, shell

Hello I have a simple example which I am confused about:

```
#!bin/bash
#test_str is a script to test whether a string is empty or not

x=''
if [ -n $x ]
then  
    echo "'$x' is not empty"
else 
    echo "'$x' empty"
fi

chmod u+x test_str
./test_str
```

The output:

```
'' is not empty
```

- This occurs also if I've not declared a variable (x here).
- If I use the flag `-z` to test for emptiness it works fine:

  ```
    if [ -z $x ]
    then  
        echo "'$x' is  empty"
    else 
        echo "'$x' not empty"
    fi
  ```

The output:

```
'' is empty
```

- So how can I use `-n` correctly?
  Thank you!

Comment: Quote it! `[ -n "$x" ]` without it, construct is evaluated as `[ -n ]` which is _always_ true

Comment: Duplicate maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852612/test-for-empty-string-with-x it's hard to find a duplicate when searching for `-n` :/

Comment: @Inian: Can you explain more please. or add it as an answer?

Comment: @Inian: It works fine thanks. One last question: should I uses `""` for the flag `-z` too or not? and if not why?

Comment: When in doubt, always look up the manual - https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html . Search for `-z string` and `-n string`

Comment: @Maestro : You will notice, that i.e. [ -ge ] also is true. See _man test_, where it says: _-n STRING : the length of STRING is nonzero_ and in the next line: _STRING equivalent to -n STRING_  Since your `[ -n $x ]` is, after expansion of the empty x,  equiavlent to `test -n`, the first variant does not apply (there is no _STRING_ anymore), but the second does: The statement is interpreted as `test -n -n`, i.e. whether the string _-n_  is not empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `[ -n $n ]` is expanded to `[ -n  ]` so there is nothing to compare and it will return `true`.

Instead, you should use `[ -n "${n}" ]` to prevent such errors *and* to prevent globbing.

Comment: Side note: if the glob character is in the value of $n, there's no globbing.

Comment: and this `[ -z $n ]` how it is interpreted?

Comment: `-z` does check the _existenze_ of the variable, not the value. But you should also use `[ -z "$n" ]` instead.