# Bash script listen for key press to move on

Tags: bash, shell

So, I want to write a bash script that are a sequence of steps and ill identify it as "task#". However, each step is only completed and can run as long as the user wants.

```
Do task1
if keypressed stop task1 and move on #this is the part I need help with. There can be up to 10 of these move on steps. 
Do task2
...
```

kina like top; it keeps doing stuff until you hit q to quite, however, i want to move on to the next thing

Comment: while loop subset: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297638/bash-how-to-end-infinite-loop-with-any-key-pressed

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can use `read` builtin command with option `-t` and `-n`

```
while :
do
    # TASK 1
    date
    read -t 1 -n 1 key

    if [[ $key = q ]]
    then
        break
    fi
done

# TASK 2
date +%s
```

Comment: @jarno: I appreciate the correction and the pointers. I've deleted my original comment and decided to dig deeper in my own answer.

Answer (score 6):

**[kev's great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9731519/45375) works well even in Bash 3.x.**, but it **introduces a *1-second delay* (`-t 1`) in every loop iteration.**

In **Bash 3.x, the lowest supported value for `-t` (timeout) is `1` (second)**, unfortunately.

**Bash 4.x supports `0` and *fractional* values**, however:

A solution that supports an **arbitrary key** such as `q` requires a *nonzero* `-t` value, but you can **specify a value very close to `0` to minimize the delay**:

```
#!/bin/bash
# !! BASH 4.x+ ONLY

while :; do

  # Loop command
  date

  # Check for 'q' keypress *waiting very briefly*  and exit the loop, if found.
  read -t 0.01 -r -s -N 1 && [[ $REPLY == 'q' ]] && break

done

# Post-loop command
date +%s
```

*Caveat*: The above uses `0.01` as the almost-no-timeout value, but, depending on your host platform, terminal program and possibly CPU speed/configuration, **a larger value may be required / a smaller value may be supported**. If the value is too small, you'll see **intermittent `error setting terminal attributes: Interrupted system call` errors** - if anyone knows why, do tell us.

---

<sup>Tip of the hat to [jarno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4414935/jarno) for his help with the following:</sup>

**Using `-t 0`**, works as follows, according to `help read` (emphasis added):

> If TIMEOUT is 0, read **returns
>     immediately**, without trying to read any data, **returning
>     success only if input is available** on the specified
>     file descriptor.

**As of Bash v4.4.12 and 5.0.11**, unfortunately, **`-t 0` seems to *ignore* `-n` / `-N`, so that only an <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keypress (or a sequence of keypresses *ending in* <kbd>ENTER</kbd>) causes `read` to indicate that data is available**.
<sup>If anyone knows whether this is a *bug* or whether there's a good reason for this behavior, do let us know.</sup>

Therefore, **only with <kbd>ENTER</kbd> as the quit key is a `-t 0` solution currently possible**:

```
#!/bin/bash
# !! BASH 4.x+ ONLY

while :; do

  # Loop command
  date

  # Check for ENTER keypress and, after clearing the input buffer
  # with a dummy `read`, exit the loop.
  read -t 0 -r -N 1 && { read -r; break; }

done

# Post-loop command
date +%s
```

Comment: getting search hit here for and researching error of **setting terminal attributes** from `bash -o monitor -c 'read -t1 -n1 -s -pp: r &'` (NB `-o monitor` for `&`), I found the error comes from builtins/read.def calling sh_ttyerror(1) in builtins/common.c when some calls matched by `grep -EHn 'tt(setattr|_set(cbreak|onechar|noecho))'` in [lib/sh/shtty.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/sh/shtty.c) fail.
(Removing the `-s` prevents one error.)

Adding `-e` for using `readline` prevents any errors for me.

Comment: Thanks, @vike. Based on your findings, is there a way to make the above work with `-t 0`?

Comment: no, the info on `-t0` checks out (as special case in read.def, independent of other opts). Though, I did find my **bash 5.0.7** seem to support `-t0.001` with only `-n1`, but `-t0.0001` with only `-N1` (independent of `-s` and/or `-r`). Oddly, `-t0.00001` as only opt seem supported, but with `-e` only `-t0.002233` does. These fractions could depend on local cpu times as `setitimer`(3) rounds to "resolution of the system clock" ("typically 10 milliseconds" in my '93 manpage), is called with ITIMER_REAL, and a CHECK_ALRM macro (from quit.h) is used at different places in read.def.

Comment: Thanks for digging deeper, @vike. Given how much research you've done already, I encourage you to submit a detailed bug report re `-t 0` (e.g. via the `bashbug` script).