# How to detect when user press ESC and do something in shell script

Tags: shell

I want to create a poll in a shell script:

echo "1 - What is your name?"
read name
echo "your name is $name"

echo "2 - What is your country?"
read country
echo "your country is $country"

...

...etc...

...

I want if the user press ESC in a question, cancel the question an jump to the next question.

Thanks! I keep in wait for possibles answers!

Comment: Which shell are you working with?

Comment: I'm using 
#!/bin/sh
...myscript...

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297638/bash-how-to-end-infinite-loop-with-any-key-pressed

Answer (score 12):

this is how to know if user selected escape :

```
read -s -n1  key

 case $key in
     $'\e') echo "Escape";;
 esac
```

Comment: This will only work in `bash` (not all operating systems use `bash` for `/bin/sh` by default).

Comment: /!\ Important precision, use `$'\e'` as-is (with the `$` and single quotes), not `$"\e"` nor `'\e'`.

Comment: Actually it doesn't detect only ESC. It's positive also at least with arrows and function keys.

Answer (score 1):

If you end up using bash shell, you might be interested in the "trap" command, which allows you to trap and act on interupts (e.g. ctrl-C)

E.g: http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3907156